If measured in different time across days, should it be crossed or nested random effects?
everyone.
I have a dataset that happiness was measured in morning, afternoon and evening(time of day) across 3-6 days for each subject.
My two questions are:

If I care about the relationship between happiness and other task variables like task performances, I guess I should include time and day as random effect. But I am not sure this is a crossed or nested random effect. That is, should I specify it as Happiness ~ performance + (1| Subjects) + (1|Days/Time), or Happiness ~ 1 + (1| Subjects) + (1|Days) + (1|Time)?

I have checked the Crossed vs nested random effects: how do they differ and how are they specified correctly in lme4?.
According to the answer, if I think the time of day are the same across days, it should be crossed, or if we think like, the morning of different days are different, it should be nested.

If now I care about how the happiness varies with time , should time still be included in random effect considering the data structure? Which means, should I specify it as Happiness ~ time + (1| Subjects) + (1|Days), or Happiness ~ Time + (1| Subjects) + (1|Days/Time) (or + (1|Days) + (1|Time)) ?

Thanks so much for any suggestions!


I am not sure whether the time of day and days should be nested or crossed.

Neither.
You have repeated measurements of subjects, but the effect of date (or time) is fixed. Only include a random effect for subjects, and include a fixed effect of time and/or date, perhaps using a spline to incorporate a non-linear relationship.
There is a useful post explaining the difference between fixed and random effects here.

Hi Frans, Thanks for your reply. I guess you are answering my second question. Actually I have two questions corrsponding to different situations. For the first one, I was wondering the relationship between happiness and other task variables like their task performances. So I guess I should include time and days as random effects, but not sure about it should be nested or corssed .

For the second question,  I care about how the happiness varies with time or day, and maybe the interation between time and task variables. So I was asking, if I include time in the fixed effect, should I still contain it in random effect considering the data structure? Thanks so much for any further help!

How happiness varies with time and task should be modelled as fixed. The days cannot be reasonably assumed to be a random draw from all the days you could have picked. The subjects can. There is no need to also include it as random.

Thanks! How about the first question? Could you please also give some suggestions about whether it should be nested or crosses

If there is only a random effect for subjects, there is no possibility for nesting or crossed random effects. An example of a nested random effect would be (1 | Hospital / Subject) (multiple hospitals, each with their own repeated measures of patients). An example of a crossed random effect would be (1 | Subject) + (1 | Researcher), where you randomly assign measurements to, say, 10 scientists and want to correct for measurement bias, while also accounting for repeated measures of patients.

Thanks so much！
